# Annoying Error #2048: Security sandbox violation from localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, crossdomain.xml

This is my crossdomain.xml that I put in the same folder of my `Web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false" />
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Although I can load using `Security.loadPolicyFile("http://localhost:52090/crossdomain.xml")`.

When my swf try to comunicate with my local site (asp.net mvc) it says:

> Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: http:/ /localhost:52090/Content/Swf/MyApp.swf cannot load data from localhost:52090

How do I solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use `as3httpclientlib` that based on `Socket`, rather than `URLLoader` you should setup socket policy server instead of http one (so your `crossdomain.xml` isn't used by flash in this case).

To setup flash policy server you can use perl script from this article http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html with policy xml suggested by @Bart Friederichs (with `to-ports` attribute)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

also, if you send it yourself, make sure to [send a null-character](http://blog.friesoft.nl/en/2012/05/22/adobe-flex-snack-error-2048-security-sandbox-violation/) in the end.

Comment: Did not work. I'm using this lib for restful comunication: https://code.google.com/p/as3httpclientlib/

Comment: Sorry, can't help you further then. All I know is that the XML should be sent on the `<policy-file_request/>` by the server. Make sure that that is the case using wireshark or so.