# Socket: Security sandbox violation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm trying to open a socket to my server, but it doesn't work, I'm always getting the famous

```
Error #2044: Unhandled securityError:. text=Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: http://zappy.mydomain.fr/ZappyGraphic.swf cannot load data from zappy.mydomain.fr:4242.
```

I have a `crossdomain.xml` at the root of my domain, looking like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false" />
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

And in my actionscript program, here is how I load the crossdomain policies

```
Security.allowDomain("*");
Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://mydomain.fr/crossdomain.xml");
```

The server is located at mydomain.fr on the port 4242 and the `swf` file is located at `http://zappy.mydomain.fr/index.html`...

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Check out this my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364372/annoying-error-2048-security-sandbox-violation-from-localhost/17365467#17365467, http crossdomain policy file doesn't used by socket, you have to setup policy socket server

Comment: @fsbmain What's the difference with my file, excepting the `allow-http-request-headers-from`?

Comment: the difference is that you use _Socket_, rather than _URLLoader_, is that true? if so, socket don't use http for loading policy file, it uses socket policy server, that required some additional setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you can not have a space at the end of the line, so:

```
<allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false" />
```

Has to be

```
<allow-acces-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
```

Thanks to make me lose my time ! :D

And, as @Gio made me notice, you have to configure a socket policy server listening on port 843. Here is my `nginx` configuration if someone needs it:

```
server {
    listen 843;
    server_name mydomain.fr;
    location / {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /crossdomain.xml;
    }

    error_page 400 /crossdomain.xml;

    location = /crossdomain.xml {
        root /usr/share/nginx/www/root;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, that's not correct. As @fsbmain said he needs a policy socket server.

Comment: @Gio Ah okay I see what you mean! Yes I actually did that (It took me seconds with nginx) and made it point to the same repository than http://mydomain.fr/ but as it was still not working because of this space, I thought it was not the solution, I edit my post.