# AS3: Weird Security sandbox violation, cannot load data from xxx.yyy.zzz:80

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, http, post, cross-domain

I am using [as3httpclient library](https://github.com/gabriel/as3httpclient/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md) which uses Flash Socket for http communication. My swf is accessed from this address:

> http://xxx.yyy.com/flash/UploadCharInfo.html

When I try to do a POST request to the server, after a few seconds I get ***exactly*** this Flash error:

> Error #2048: Security sandbox violation:
>   http://xxx.yyy.com/flash/UploadCharInfo.swf?1439403065 cannot
>   load data from [xxx.yyy.com:80](http://xxx.yyy.com:80).

I have put this cross-domain policy xml:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

at
http://xxx.yyy.com/crossdomain.xml

In my code I have put at the top of the code:

```
    Security.allowDomain("*");
    Security.loadPolicyFile("http://xxx.yyy.com/crossdomain.xml");
```

I still get the dreaded #2048 error. What else is there to try?!

PS. My code works fine from within Flash Builder's debugging sandbox. The error appears when I try to play my swf online.

PS2. Just found another ***VERY*** similar answer here:[Annoying Error #2048: Security sandbox violation from localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364372/annoying-error-2048-security-sandbox-violation-from-localhost/17365467#17365467)

Comment: What does the POST request look like?

Comment: @null var client:HttpClient = new HttpClient();
var uri:URI = new URI("http://www.snee.com/xml/crud/posttest.cgi");
var variables:Array = [{name:"fname", value:"FirstName1"}, {name:"lname", value: "LastName1"}];

client.listener.onData = function(event:HttpDataEvent):void {
  // Notified with response content in event.bytes as it streams in
};

client.listener.onComplete = function(event:HttpResponseEvent):void {
  // Notified when complete (after status and data)
};

client.postFormData(uri, variables);